# Simplest tool for mini-doc generation based on functions annotations

Tags: python, annotations, robotframework, documentation

Firstly, I know there are several tools existing that may greatly helps documentation generation in Python Project.

(Sphinx, Doxygen and such.)

Maybe they are adapted and can be used with an option or by using right setup.
But they seems to be really big, fat systems that can generate docs in web formats, with even charts, images, stats...

I don't think I need something like this, I will describe my problematic and the way i imagine my documentation:

---

Project is related to RobotFramework, a test framework with it's own language for test description.
We can call python functions within it, using Keywords, representing the functions.

Python function looks like this:

```
@keyword(name='Extract tool ${tool} optimization using connection ${connection} in ${run_path}')
def extract_tool_optimization(self, tool, connection, run_path):
```

RobotFramework syntax may looks like this:

```
${STATUS} =  Extract tool ${first_tool} optimization using connection ${first_connection} in ${run_path}
```

I would want to annotate / comment classes and functions of the python code.

For example:

```
''' 
Keyword to extract tool optimization, using SSH connection object, path for export needs to be provided
A boolean status is returned depending on success or not.
'''
@keyword(name='Extract tool ${tool} optimization using connection ${connection} in ${run_path}')
def extract_tool_optimization(self, tool, connection, run_path):
```

---

Then I would want to run some documentation tool, on the whole project:

This tool should generate a simple database file (can be text, web, docx..) with the usage description of all available Keywords.

Including the comment, **and** the @keyword annotation with phrase to be used in RobotFramework.

I would then be able to send Test Creators this updated "database", which will greatly help them to use all the Python Keywords available.

The produced result will NOT be specially for developers.

Is there a tool that may help this subject, or should I try to parse / regex myself into it ?

Thanks

Comment: One link for you - the vanilla RF tool for that: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#library-documentation-tool-libdoc

Comment: @TodorMinakov Didn't even know that was existing, many thanks, I will look into it !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @TodorMinakov

Simply using the vanilla tool already proposed by RF (for anyone not knowing it):

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#library-documentation-tool-libdoc